# The String Replace function in PHP is not working for me

Tags: php

I have an $events array and I want to remove every instance of a string within it it, but when I try this, and then print the array, I don't see the difference. Is there something I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
$events = myFunctionToGetData("theDataFile.ics");
$events = str_replace(";VALUE=DATE", "", $events);

print("<pre>".print_r($events,true)."</pre>");
```

I know the $events is getting the data because printing it shows the data, but it doesn't show that string was replaced.

Here are two of the results I get. You can see that one result gives uses [DTSTART] and the other uses [DTSTART;VALUE=DATE]. I want it change all instances of [DTSTART;VALUE=DATE] to just [DTSTART] so that I can loop through and get all of the events by date.

```
    [3] => Array
        (
            [BEGIN] => VEVENT
            [CREATED] => 20200302T212345Z
            [DESCRIPTION] => DTEND:20200324T180000ZDTSTAMP:20200418T211011ZDTSTART:20200324T150000ZLAST-MODIFIED:20200302T212345ZLOCATION:Lower Communication LobbySEQUENCE:0STATUS:ConfirmedSUMMARY:Grand Canyon University Table VisitTRANSP:OpaqueUID:e7ca75ad-289f-463b-a61f-c163bf6a1a2a
            [DTEND] => 20200324T180000Z
            [DTSTAMP] => 20200418T211011Z
            [DTSTART] => 20200324T150000Z
            [LAST-MODIFIED] => 20200302T212345Z
            [LOCATION] => Lower Communication Lobby
            [SEQUENCE] => 0
            [STATUS] => Confirmed
            [SUMMARY] => Grand Canyon University Table Visit
            [TRANSP] => Opaque
            [UID] => e7ca75ad-289f-463b-a61f-c163bf6a1a2a
            [END] => VEVENT
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [BEGIN] => VEVENT
            [CREATED] => 20190812T155732Z
            [DESCRIPTION] => 
Wear your favorite March Madness gear to show support for y our team or wear your Logan Blue to support your Volunteers.

DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20200328DTSTAMP:20200418T211011ZDTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20200327LAST-MODIFIED:20190812T155732ZSEQUENCE:0STATUS:ConfirmedSUMMARY:March Madness Day!TRANSP:OpaqueUID:11f2de6e-bdee-4c44-8b50-fa0a44d46c54
            [DTEND;VALUE=DATE] => 20200328
            [DTSTAMP] => 20200418T211011Z
            [DTSTART;VALUE=DATE] => 20200327
            [LAST-MODIFIED] => 20190812T155732Z
            [SEQUENCE] => 0
            [STATUS] => Confirmed
            [SUMMARY] => March Madness Day!
            [TRANSP] => Opaque
            [UID] => 11f2de6e-bdee-4c44-8b50-fa0a44d46c54
            [END] => VEVENT
        )
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the first $events has the expected value? Could you add it? str_replace works only for strings

Comment: Yes, I thought that any text could be considered a string. The problem is the ical I am getting the information from gives me data presented in two different ways depending on if it is an all day event. 
[DTSTART] => 20200324T150000Z
[DTSTART;VALUE=DATE] => 20200327
I want it to only use [DTSTART] because I want to loop through and get all of the dates.    It does not matter to me if it is an all day event. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you append the result of `var_dump($events);` to your question please. And maybe clarify exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: I added more to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You should show what is in `$events` and what is output as error messages or the final output in your `<pre>` tag

> I have an $events array ...

If its an array you need to iterate over that array, you can not use `str_replace` on an array.

```
$events = myFunctionToGetData("theDataFile.ics");

foreach ( $events as $key => $nested_array ) {

    foreach ( $nested_array as $nested_key => $val ) {
        $events[ $key ][ $nested_key ] = str_replace( ";VALUE=DATE", "", $val );
    }
}

print( "<pre>" . print_r( $events, true ) . "</pre>" );
```

Comment: I added more to the original post.

Comment: OK you got a nested array so you need another loop. I updated the answer and that should do it. Do not forget to accept my answer.

Comment: For some reason that is still not removing it from my results. Do I need to change anything in the code you are providing?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I ended up solving the problem. I went back into the function and modified the results of the file before it go turned into an array.

```
$newfile = file_get_contents("theDataFile.ics");
$newfile = str_replace(';VALUE=DATE', '', $newfile);
$mycalendarvariable = $newfile;
```

Since the file is now in the function, I do not pass anything to myFunctionToGetData. It is just

```
$events = myFunctionToGetData();
```

It might not be the most elegant way to do it, but it worked.